# kableExtra::kable problem when knit to pdf with footnote hline and booktabs = TRUE

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

My attempt is to highlight a row with two hlines in a longtable pdf output. It works as long the row to highlight is not the last row of the table and/ or as long booktabs = FALSE in kable(). In the following a reproducible example with a small table to show the problem that occurs when the row to highlight is the last row and when (as wished) booktabs = TRUE in kable(). Please note you have to knit to pdf to see something.

The first table shows the problem: an additional row (with a * symbol) occurs.

As i read elsewhere i tried to integrate header-includes: - \usepackage{booktabs} in the YAML, but it did not change anything.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? And/ or reasons?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
---
title: "problem footnote hline longtable"
author: "author"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

row_to_highlight <- 5

# not work with booktabs = TRUE in kable()
dt  %>%
  mutate(dispfootnote = case_when(disp > 200  ~ paste0(as.character(disp), footnote_marker_alphabet(1)),
                                TRUE ~ paste0(disp))
                                ) %>%
  relocate(dispfootnote, .after = disp)%>%
  select(-disp)%>%
  kableExtra::kable(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE, caption = "not work with booktabs = TRUE in kable()",  longtable = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec(row_to_highlight, hline_after = TRUE)%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec((row_to_highlight -1), hline_after = TRUE)%>% 
  footnote(alphabet = c("disp with my footnote"),
           alphabet_title =  "Note: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T) 

# works without booktabs = TRUE in kable()
dt  %>%
  mutate(dispfootnote = case_when(disp > 200  ~ paste0(as.character(disp), footnote_marker_alphabet(1)),
                                TRUE ~ paste0(disp))
                                ) %>%
  relocate(dispfootnote, .after = disp)%>%
  select(-disp)%>%
  kableExtra::kable(booktabs = FALSE, escape = FALSE, caption = "works without booktabs = TRUE in kable()", longtable = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec(row_to_highlight, hline_after = TRUE)%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec((row_to_highlight -1), hline_after = TRUE)%>%
  footnote(alphabet = c("disp with my footnote"),
           alphabet_title =  "Note: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T) 

# works without highlighted hline after the last row
dt  %>%
  mutate(dispfootnote = case_when(disp > 200  ~ paste0(as.character(disp), footnote_marker_alphabet(1)),
                                TRUE ~ paste0(disp))
                                ) %>%
  relocate(dispfootnote, .after = disp)%>%
  select(-disp)%>%
  kableExtra::kable(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE, caption = "works without highlighted hline after the last row", longtable = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))%>%
  #kableExtra::row_spec(row_to_highlight, hline_after = TRUE)%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec((row_to_highlight -1), hline_after = TRUE)%>% 
  footnote(alphabet = c("disp with my footnote"),
           alphabet_title =  "Note: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T)
```

here is a picture which shows the problem described
[please see in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkJlk.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works right, you only forgot to add f.e. `background = "yellow"` to `row_spec`.

````
---
title: "problem footnote hline"
author: "author"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---


```{r setup, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r tables, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

row_to_highlight <- 5

# not work with booktabs = TRUE in kable()
dt  %>%
  mutate(dispfootnote = case_when(disp > 200  ~ paste0(as.character(disp), footnote_marker_alphabet(1)),
                                TRUE ~ paste0(disp))
                                ) %>%
  relocate(dispfootnote, .after = disp)%>%
  select(-disp)%>%
  kableExtra::kable(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE, caption = "not work with booktabs = TRUE in kable()",  longtable = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec(row_to_highlight, hline_after = TRUE, background = "yellow")%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec((row_to_highlight -1), hline_after = TRUE, background = "yellow")%>% 
  footnote(alphabet = c("disp with my footnote"),
           alphabet_title =  "Note: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T) 

# works without booktabs = TRUE in kable()
dt  %>%
  mutate(dispfootnote = case_when(disp > 200  ~ paste0(as.character(disp), footnote_marker_alphabet(1)),
                                TRUE ~ paste0(disp))
                                ) %>%
  relocate(dispfootnote, .after = disp)%>%
  select(-disp)%>%
  kableExtra::kable(booktabs = FALSE, escape = FALSE, caption = "works without booktabs = TRUE in kable()", longtable = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec(row_to_highlight, hline_after = TRUE, background = "yellow")%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec((row_to_highlight -1), hline_after = TRUE, background = "yellow")%>%
  footnote(alphabet = c("disp with my footnote"),
           alphabet_title =  "Note: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T) 


# works without highlighted hline after the last row
dt  %>%
  mutate(dispfootnote = case_when(disp > 200  ~ paste0(as.character(disp), footnote_marker_alphabet(1)),
                                TRUE ~ paste0(disp))
                                ) %>%
  relocate(dispfootnote, .after = disp)%>%
  select(-disp)%>%
  kableExtra::kable(booktabs = TRUE, escape = FALSE, caption = "works without highlighted hline after the last row", longtable = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))%>%
  #kableExtra::row_spec(row_to_highlight, hline_after = TRUE)%>%
  kableExtra::row_spec((row_to_highlight -1), hline_after = TRUE, background = "yellow")%>% 
  footnote(alphabet = c("disp with my footnote"),
           alphabet_title =  "Note: ",
           footnote_as_chunk = T)  
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time and trying to help me. Unfortunately, the addition of background = "yellow" does not change anything for me (independently if adding to one or both hlines). I.e. there still appears an additional row (with a * symbol). I will try to add a picture immediately at the end of my question...

Comment: I now added a picture (as the addition of background = "yellow" did not change anything for me without this part of code) at the end of my question...

Comment: @str2ive man, it is strange, Try to update your packages ```rmarkdown/markdown/kableextra``` and re-knit. And let's see after.

Comment: I did so (also) before posting this question, without success. I just agree it is strange as it just happens when longtable = TRUE, a hline_after is at the end of a table and booktabs = TRUE. But in this order, it’s what I have, can happen more often than not and how it should look like. Were you able to reproduce it!?

Comment: @str2ive I don't know, as you see, it works in every case. You can also try to install texlive instead of your existing TeX-distro.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly if you could reproduce my error or not. Because your picture shows tab 1 with booktabs = FALSE as I think; i.e. not what I'm trying to do and not the code I presented. Correct me if I am wrong. Generally I have installed and updated tinytex, as well as kableExtra.

Comment: @str2ive I simply took your code...

Comment: when i take your code (compared to the mine: addition of background = "yellow"), i do not get the output you show in your picture. I.e. table 1 in the output (as wished) with booktabs = TRUE and (as not wished) the described problem remains... Maybe you rerun the code you posted here in a new file to check..?

Comment: @str2ive I did it for you, all right. I think, that problem somewhere at your side, but don't know exactly where.

Comment: thanks for doing so - in this case either your picture is wrong or if the picture is really what you get when knitting the code posted, then the output table 1 at your side is wrong in sense of there are vertical lines (booktabs = TRUE would be ignored)

Comment: @str2ive I forgot to change the pic...

Comment: So, here we are!! obviously you are facing exactly the same problem as me - in table 1 an additional row (with a * symbol) occurs...

Comment: @str2ive Hah, maybe, it is a bug) Try to open an issue at github :)